# Loop to delete blank cells from a column

Tags: vba, excel

I need to delete the blank cells in column F from F4 on down.  There will be between 0 and lots of blank cells per row.

I'm very new to coding, and my most successful approach has been to take code that did something similar and cannibalized it.

Here's the code that worked for something similar:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 4 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        Do While .Cells(i, "F").Value2 = .Cells(1, "B").Value2 And Not 
IsEmpty(.Cells(i, "F"))
            .Cells(i, "F").Resize(1, 4).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
        Loop
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

And here's what I tried to do with it:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
With Worksheets("sheet1")
For i = 4 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    Do While .Cells(i, "F").Value2 = ""
        .Cells(i, "F").Resize(1, 4).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
    Loop
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

I don't get any errors when I run it, but it doesn't work either.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't very descriptive and without seeing an example of your data or knowing what you're trying to *do*, it's tough to help.  My only suggestion at this point is to **step through the code** line by line, monitoring the values of your variables, to figure out what's going on.  See Chip Pearson's [**Debugging VBA**](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx).

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me. Are the values in column F what you expect them to be?  BTW, `Do While .Cells(i, "F").Value2 = ""` is potentially an infinite loop if you happen to delete everything to the right of it.

Comment: True, "it doesn't work" wasn't very helpful on my part.  What I meant was that running the macro didn't produce any change to the spreadsheet.  Got it working now, though, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow as integer

With Worksheets("sheet1")
lastrow= cells(rows.count, 6).end(xlup).row     'define your last filled row

For i = 4 To lastrow
    if IsEmpty(cells(i,6))= TRUE then
    Cells(i,6).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

However, I normally find deleting cells from the bottom up works better. So....perhaps you could try this as well:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow as integer

With Worksheets("sheet1")
lastrow= cells(rows.count, 6).end(xlup).row     'define your last filled row

For i = lastrow To 4 step -1
    if IsEmpty(cells(i,6))= TRUE then
    Cells(i,6).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!!  This helped a lot.  I changed the If Then into a Do While loop and it works like a dream now.

Comment: @JamesG please upvote and mark the solution as the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting blank cells by shifting the cells to the right in their place. If these cells are blank too, nothing will appear to change. If you want to remove the entire row instead, change your code to this:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
With Worksheets("sheet1")
For i =  .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row to 4 Step-1
    IF .Cells(i, "F").Value2 = ""
        .Cells(i, "F").entirerow.Delete shift:=xlUp
    Loop
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 
 1. intent of the code is to only eliminate blanks in column F
 2. deletion of entire row is uncalled for.
 3. deleting cell xlLeft will inadvertently put the content (or blank cell) of Column G into column F.
 the following code may be tried

```
   Sub test()
   Dim i As Long
   With Worksheets("sheet1")
   For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row To 4 Step -1
       If .Cells(i, "F").Value2 = "" Then
      .Range(.Cells(i + 1, "F"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row, "F")).Cut
      .Cells(i, "F").Select
      .Paste
       End If
    Next i
    End With
    End Sub
```